# Is there a max file size when uploading as a Multipart File

Tags: java, vaadin, multipartentity

```
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(properties.getPropert("system.api.url"));
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, event.getMIMEType()));
            post.setEntity(entity);
```

This is how I upload the file as a Multipart file to my rest controller. Is  there a max file size that can be uploaded or is there any way that I can define a max file size foe this kind of uploading. I use this code in my Vaadin client side.

Comment: The max file size will be defined on the server side. There are a few settings you can set either through your servlet container or your web framework.

Comment: In the server side I have restricted that as                   <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->
         
        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->
 
    </bean>

Comment: Pretty sure that's all you need.

Comment: Should complete your question with server side code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your config:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize(env.getRequiredProperty("MAX.FILE.SIZE"));
    factory.setMaxRequestSize(env.getRequiredProperty("MAX.FILES.SIZE"));
    factory.setFileSizeThreshold(env.getRequiredProperty("MAX.MEMORY.SIZE"));
    factory.setLocation(env.getRequiredProperty("IMAGE.PROCESSOR.UPLOADTMP"));

    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

I assume that env is Spring configuration environment variables.
Or just put values instead.