# How to check if file totally uploaded on Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using Spring MVC in my application where I have requirement to upload a file.
And if the file size is greater than 30 MB we need to call other third party service and send error back to UI.

As we need to call other services after checking file size, I have written code inside my Spring controller to check file size. But it did not give me error even though file size greater than 30 MB.

Code snippet is as below :

```
public ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> storeUploadedDocument(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException { 

    long fileSize = file.getSize();

    if (fileSize > (30 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        //File size if greater than 30 MB

        // Call thirdparty service for remaining process

        // send error code back to ui
    }

}
```

As per few references, MultipartFile.getSize() will not return full file size but it will return only size of the file which was uploaded while calling this method.

So, is it possible to check, if file upload process has been completed and to check total file size ?

How can we achieve this functionality on Spring Controller ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394259/is-there-a-max-file-size-when-uploading-as-a-multipart-file

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the way Spring `MultipartFile` works.

The spring mvc ServletDispatcher calls `checkMultipart` early on in its  doDispatch:

```
protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest processedRequest = request;
    HandlerExecutionChain mappedHandler = null;
    boolean multipartRequestParsed = false;

    WebAsyncManager asyncManager = WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(request);

    try {
        ModelAndView mv = null;
        Exception dispatchException = null;

        try {
            processedRequest = checkMultipart(request);
```

and `checkMultipart` ultimately delegates to `request.getParts()`:

```
private void parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
```

and therefore the real answer is that it will depend on how your application server implements the parsing of multipart/formdata requests.

Tomcat's `getParts` implementation, for example, uploads files to temporary files before returning from this method and therefore the files are already uploaded by the time an instance of `MultipartFile` is passed to your Contoller.

Other app servers may behave differently but I doubt it, honestly.  Either way you dont want to rely on one behavior.  Better to find a different, reliable, solution.  Like, for example, limiting the size of file upload via this endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation of server dependent behavior of MultiPart implementation. Last option is to configure max file upload size in MultipartResolver. But I am searching for other solution, so I can customize my response codes and further service calls if file size is greater than 30 MB.